# Video Play through intent from assets folder in android

Tags: android, android-video-player

i WAnna play a video that is in my assets folder. that can be played in any player installed in android.
Help OuT

Answer (score 2):

Take a video view and media player in layout and in your activity onCreate you can do this

> ```
> private VideoView video;
> private MediaController ctlr;
> uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://packagename/" + R.raw.famous);
> video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
> video.setVideoURI(uri);
> ctlr=new MediaController(this);
> ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
> video.setMediaController(ctlr);
> video.requestFocus();
> video.start();
> ```

Here the video named famous is in raw folder in res. or you can keep in assets and change the file name based on that.
Code is tested and it works fine.

Comment: hi sir how are you ,@NipunGogia

Comment: @swati i wanna play that video in Default Player, not in video view

Comment: is there any function in intent just like we open pdf viewer of a system

Comment: yah just like that , just wanna play a video

Comment: File file = new File("fileUri");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1):

check this out :

```
Intent viewMediaIntent = new Intent();   
          viewMediaIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);        
          Uri audio = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.audio.test/raw/"+R.raw.audio1);       
          Log.d(TAG,"uri:"+audio.toString());
          viewMediaIntent.setDataAndType(audio, "video/*");   
          viewMediaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
          Log.d(TAG,"Starting");
          Intent i = Intent.createChooser(viewMediaIntent, "Play Music");
            mGap.startActivity(i);
          Log.d(TAG,"Started");
```

Comment: it is showing  a message , "no Application can perform this Action"